# Angular formArray radio buttons

Tags: angular

I am attempting to add a radio button group to a FormArray. The issue is that when I select a value, it changes the value for every member of the FormArray. I know this has to do with the formControlName, but **I don't know how to make the formControlName dynamic**. I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251876/formgroup-containing-radio-buttons-with-an-angular-formarray) but it's 4 years old and a little vague; i.e., I couldn't come to a clear answer therefrom.

This is what I currently have:

#### TS component

```
//inputs and variable initialization

ngOnInit() {
  this.createSensorForm();
}

createSensorForm() {
    this.sensorForm = this.fb.group({
      ...
      definitions: this.fb.array([this.createDefinition()])
  });
}

createDefinition(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    numeric: [""],
  });
}

addDefinition() {
  this.definitions = this.sensorForm.get('definitions') as FormArray;
  this.definitions.push(this.createDefinition());
}
```

#### HTML component

```
<form [formGroup]="sensorForm" (ngSubmit)="createSensor()">
  ...
  <div formArrayName="definitions" 
       *ngFor="let definition of sensorForm.get('definitions').controls; let i = index;">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      ...
      <input type="radio" [value]="true" 
             formControlName="numeric" [(ngModel)]="numeric"> Yes
      <input type="radio" [value]="false" 
             formControlName="numeric" [(ngModel)]="numeric"> No
    </div>
  </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="addDefinition()">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Definition
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf="sensorForm"  [formGroup]="sensorForm" (ngSubmit)="createSensor()>
  <!---first the name of array-->
  <div formArrayName="definitions">
      <!--after the loop using a div, this div has [fromGroupName]=i -->
      <div *ngFor="let definition of sensorForm.get('definitions').controls; 
                  let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
          <!--each element, only use formControlName, ¡NOT! [(ngModel)] -->
          <!-- ngModel is for Template driven Form  -->
          <input type="radio" [value]="true" formControlName="numeric" > Yes
          <input type="radio" [value]="false" formControlName="numeric" > No
      </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Your addDefinition is wrong, you have not "this.definitions"

```
addDefinition() {
    const definitions = this.sensorForm.get('definitions') as FormArray;
    definitions.push(this.createDefinition());
  }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a million!

Comment: be carefull, I update the answer adding the code to addDefinition