# Angular - Populate form array input on edit

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngxs

I have a quantity field and an "Add" button. On click of button new fields for quantity gets added as well as Delete button to remove it.
I have used Form array for it

My code is as below

```
<div formArrayName="ingredients11">
 <!-- loop throught units -->
 <div *ngFor="let unit of recipeForm['controls'].ingredients11['controls']; let i = index ">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Quantity</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="recipe_ingredient_quantity">
    <div *ngIf="unit['controls'].recipe_ingredient_quantity.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
     <div *ngIf="unit['controls'].recipe_ingredient.errors.required">
      Quantity is required.
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-danger" *ngIf="recipeForm['controls'].ingredients11['controls'].length > 1" (click)="remove(i)">Delete</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="add()">Add</button>
</div>
```

I also have an edit functionality, where I want to pre-populate the number of quantity fields and their values saved previously for edit

My code is as below:

```
<div formArrayName="ingredients11">
  <!-- loop throught units -->
  <div *ngFor="let unit of editrecipeForm['controls'].ingredients11['controls']; let i = index ">
   <!-- row divider show for every nex row exclude if first row -->
   <div *ngIf="editrecipeForm['controls'].ingredients11['controls'].length > 1 && i > 0" ><hr></div>
   <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let ri of editingredientsarray;">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Ingredients</label>
     <select class="form-control" formControlName="recipe_ingredient" >
      <option value="">Select Ingredient</option>
      <option *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients | async" [value]="ingredient.id">
       {{ingredient.name}}
      </option>
     </select>
     <div *ngIf="unit['controls'].recipe_ingredient.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="unit['controls'].recipe_ingredient.errors.required">
       Ingredient is required.
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Quantity</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="recipe_ingredient_quantity" [value]="ri.quantity">
     <div *ngIf="unit['controls'].recipe_ingredient_quantity.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="unit['controls'].recipe_ingredient.errors.required">
       Quantity is required.
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" *ngIf="editrecipeForm['controls'].ingredients11['controls'].length > 1" (click)="removeEditIngredient(i)(i)">Delete Ingredient</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addEditIngredient()">Add New Ingredient</button>
 </div>
```

But the value is not populating in input field. Can anyone please guide

Comment: It looks like binding issue.That will be great if you can create field(https://stackblitz.com) for us to know what exactly you doing in .ts file

Comment: can you share your ts code

Comment: There are a lot of examples in web, the official docs, https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays, an e.g. with radio buttons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427333/angular-formarray-radio-buttons/51427819#51427819, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state is configured wrongly :

```
export const Users = [
  {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "aaa",
      "technology": "1" //<------ Use id instead of names
  },
  {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "bbb",
      "technology": "1,2" //<------ Use id instead of names
  },
  {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "ccc",
      "technology": "1,3" //<------ Use id instead of names
  }
]
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngxs-select-form-solved)**

Comment: in the working demo tech 3 is selected in both drop downs, but for first it should be tech 1. Please provide solution for this

Comment: Please let me know solution.it's urgent

Comment: @Abhijit , there is some issue with your form builder , and names.

Comment: Should names in form array be unique? If yes how should we name the fields in formArray

Comment: can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are binding your quantity field with `ri.quantity` so you have to pass this object in your edit function and change the value in the same object i.e. `ri` in your component ts file like,

```
edit(ri){
    ri.quantity=SOME_NEW_VALUE_HERE;
}
```

Updated, for adding selected attribute in options,

```
<option ... [selected]="ingredient.id==ri.ingredient">
   {{ingredient.name}}
</option>
```

Comment: Already in edit function I am creating and array editingredientsarray and passing it, and using it in view like - *ngFor="let ri of editingredientsarray;" <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="recipe_ingredient_quantity" [ngModel]="ri.quantity">

Comment: try to remove the formControlName from the text field

Comment: I have figured it out. We can use [value] = "ri.quantity" instead of [ngModel]="ri.quantity"
Can anyone help with showing the selected value of Ingredient dropdown if it matches ri.ingredient

Comment: Where is your dropdown?

Comment: I have updated my question code."recipe_ingredient"  is my dropdown

Comment: I have updated my answer. I was just curious to know about your project. Is this like recipes site?

Comment: change `=` to `==` in the selected condition and try.

Comment: Make sure you are having a value in `ri.ingredient`.

Comment: I have value in ri.ingredient. example: 1