# Angular - Set Selected value in Dropdown

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngxs

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="recipe_ingredient">
          <option value="">Select Ingredient</option>
          <option *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients | async" [value]="ingredient.id" [selected]="ingredient.id == ri.ingredient">
           {{ingredient.id}}-{{ingredient.name}}
          </option>
```

ri.ingredient = 2; But below does not return true in above code so value is not selected

```
ingredient.id == ri.ingredient
```

can any one please guide

The code in my ts file is as below:

```
editRecipeForm() {
    this.editrecipeForm = this.fb.group({
      recipe_name: ['', Validators.required ],
      recipe_description: ['', Validators.required ],
      edit_recipe_image: [],
      ingredients11: this.fb.array([
         this.getIngredient()
      ])
   });
  } 12:49 
getIngredient() {
    return this.fb.group({
     recipe_ingredient: ['', Validators.required ],
      recipe_ingredient_quantity: ['', Validators.required ]
    });
  }
```

Comment: have you try setting the `<option ng-selected="ingredient"></option>` this should item in the collection

Comment: @Eldho  it does not works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you need is `ngModel` in `select` tag :

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="recipe_ingredient" [(ngModel)]="ri.ingredient">
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngxs-select-form)**

Comment: I tried it, but it return error - "main.9c580da952e68217c3e4.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'required' of null
    at Object.updateDirectives (main.9c580da952e68217c3e4.js:1)
    at Object.updateDirectives"

I have posted detail code on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625636/angular-populate-form-array-input-on-edit

Also updated question with ts file code.

Can you please check if I am missing anything

Comment: I have created demo on   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngxs-select-form-xzsp9o?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html  
Please check. & let me know the solution